# Why won't function key=randint(1,71) work?

Tags: python-3.x

I've just started to use Python 3 (about 10 minutes ago) and I'm not sure on the syntax for the following string of code:

```
if key==0
  key=randint(1,71)
  print ('Your key is', key)
```

The issue is at the 'y' in 'key' on the 2nd line. The syntax arrow indicator points to the y. What do I add/remove? I'd like the following output to be this:

```
Please select a key or type 0 to create one. (1-71) '0'
Your key is 43
```

The 0 represents the number chosen and the 43 is the random number. The real problem is this:

```
key=randint(1,71)
```

Please tell me what the problem is here. The code just will not work. What do I add/remove?

Comment: Don't describe what the error message looks like. Copy and paste the entire error into your question.

Comment: In Python you write: `if key == 0:` Notice the `:` in the end. You should probably go over some basic tutorials online

Answer (score 0):

That is because you've forgotten `:` after `if`, once you add it, it will work:

```py
>>> key = 0
>>> if key==0:
...  key=randint(1,71)
...  print ('Your key is', key)
...
Your key is 53
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import random
key = 0
if key==0:
  key=random.randint(1,71)
  print ('Your key is', key)
```